# How to create public Arrays of game objects so that they can be assigned through inspector

Tags: c#, unity

I am making a unity2D game. I need to declare public array of gameobjects so that I can assign them colliders, textures through inspector by drag n drop.
Is there any way to do this? I am using c#.

I found but not able to figure this out.[Here is one link that is not useful for me please tell why???](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/245024/public-array-of-gameobjects.html)

Comment: which is exactly your problem? could you tell us what have you tried so far and what do you have trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need a public array for that? If you just want to create `GameObject` by drag and dropping you can do that in the **Scene hierarhcy**.

If you need to access them later in a script then you can declare a public list:

```
public List<GameObject> myList = new List();
```

Then just drag and drop the objects to that list.